# Como criar serviço de streaming com python e django

Tags: python, django, vídeo, streaming

Tenho o propósito de criar um serviço de Streaming de vídeos, o projeto é em python e django.
Como faço para disponibilizar tal serviço?
Uso python 2.7 e django 1.10.

Só encontrei material antigo!

Grato pela atenção !

Comment: Você já tem toda a aplicação pronta, só precisa fazer o deploy?

Comment: Só preciso fazer funcionar o serviço de streaming.

Comment: Já tenho todo o resto do sistema pronto!

Comment: Talvez isso ajude? https://klauslaube.com.br/2017/05/14/streaming-dados-django.html; se resolver seu problema, não se esqueça de postar a solução aqui.

Comment: Vou testar esta solução!